# Accessing an element and its successor in a list at the same time

Tags: c++, list, iterator

I have a list and when iterating over it i want to access the element at the iterator and the following element at the iterator+1 at the same time. Here is my attempt:

```
std::list<Team*> teamlist = league.GetTeamMembers();
for (std::list<Team*> ::iterator iterator = teamlist.begin(); iterator !=   teamlist.end(); std::advance(iterator,2))
{
  match(*(*iterator), *(*(++iterator)));
}
```

The match function does nothing to the iterators, it just get's some values of the teams out of it to calculate a match result.

But the ++iterator does not work, as the elements in the matchfunction are still the same. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could avoid increasing the iterator at increment part of the loop and dot it in the body:

```
std::list<Team*> teamlist = league.GetTeamMembers();
for (std::list<Team*> ::iterator it = teamlist.begin();
     it !=   teamlist.end(); /*Nothing here*/)
{
    match(*(*it), *(*(++it))); //Which parameter expression is evaluated first isn't determined
    ++it;
    ...
    ...
```

**EDIT:**

As FredOverflow has pointed out, match parameter expressions evaluations are not guaranteed to run in the left to right order. To avoid this hazardous situation:

```
std::list<Team*> teamlist = league.GetTeamMembers();
for (std::list<Team*> ::iterator it = teamlist.begin();
     it !=   teamlist.end(); /*Nothing here*/)
{
    Team *pa = *it;
    Team *pb = *(++it);
    match(*pa, *pb);
    ++it;
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: `match(*(*it), *(*(++it)))` invokes undefined behavior, because the evaluation order of function arguments is unspecified.

Comment: @FredOverflow I wanted to demostrate the point that the increment doesn't need to be in the loop increment group. You can always declare to variables, fill the ins the right order and use these as match parameters.

Comment: So it works but it is somehow not safe and cn invoke undefined behavior ?

Comment: Okay everything works out niceley but could you explain me the edits in short form in your post ?

Comment: @jimbo999 Of course, already edited the answer adding some explanations.

Answer (score 2):

Passing the iterator and operating on the iterator in the same pass (like increment of the iterator) leads to undefined behavior. There are certain concepts such as [sequence points](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d45c7a5d.aspx), which you should be aware of when you are performing such operations.

Further, you can check [this](http://c-faq.com/expr/seqpoints.html) link also. I suggest you to move the increment of the operator after the pass to function. Then it should work fine.

Comment: I editet my post, as i don't operate on the iterators i just want to have the next team's informations. If that is what you mean by operating on an iterator, than you're right ;)

Comment: Basically, ++iterator would be a culprit. We cannot confirm if the expression is evaluated from R to L or L to right. So we cannot confirm it *(*(++iterator)) is evaluated Before/After *(*iterator). So the Bug.

Answer (score 1):

you are increasing the iterator twice, first in the head of the for-loop:

```
std::advance(it,2)
```

then in the loop-body, where you do a:

```
++it
```

Is this really what you want? It looks pretty confusing to me.

If you want the element next to it, but dont want to increase it, better use:

```
auto nextIt = std::next(it);
```

Also: What does the match-function do? Are you sure its implemented right and not the source of the bug?

Hope this helps

Alexander

Comment: it works right, i'm sure ;) because at the moment it just prints something out. This works too, thx